# Visually separate adjacent geom_segements from each other

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting gaze directions in conversation using `geom_segment`. As I need to use similar colors for the segments, it is often difficult to see where one segment ends and another begins. How can I insert segmenting visual elements (perhaps rectangles or vlines) to make the separation of distinct segments visually more immediate?

```
   library(ggnewscale)
   ggplot(data = df1, 
           aes(x = start, xend = end,
               y = MM_by, yend = MM_by,               
               color = MM_annotation)) +
      geom_segment(size = 4) +
      scale_y_discrete(name = NULL, limits = rev) +        
      facet_wrap(~ Utterance, scales = "free_x", ncol = 1) +
  
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("*" = "white",    
                                 "A" = "yellow",    
                                 "B" = "lawngreen",
                                 "C" = "cyan"),   
                      # rename legend key:
                      name = "Gaze to")
```

[image]

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Line = c(569L, 569L, 569L, 569L, 569L, 569L, 569L, 
569L, 569L, 569L, 570L, 570L, 570L, 570L, 571L, 571L, 571L, 573L, 
573L, 573L, 573L, 573L, 573L), Speaker = c("ID01.C", "ID01.C", 
"ID01.C", "ID01.C", "ID01.C", "ID01.C", "ID01.C", "ID01.C", "ID01.C", 
"ID01.C", NA, NA, NA, NA, "ID01.C", "ID01.C", "ID01.C", "ID01.A", 
"ID01.A", "ID01.A", "ID01.A", "ID01.A", "ID01.A"), Timestamp = c("00:12:02.300 - 00:12:04.113", 
"00:12:02.300 - 00:12:04.113", "00:12:02.300 - 00:12:04.113", 
"00:12:02.300 - 00:12:04.113", "00:12:02.300 - 00:12:04.113", 
"00:12:02.300 - 00:12:04.113", "00:12:02.300 - 00:12:04.113", 
"00:12:02.300 - 00:12:04.113", "00:12:02.300 - 00:12:04.113", 
"00:12:02.300 - 00:12:04.113", "00:12:04.113 - 00:12:04.667", 
"00:12:04.113 - 00:12:04.667", "00:12:04.113 - 00:12:04.667", 
"00:12:04.113 - 00:12:04.667", "00:12:04.667 - 00:12:05.737", 
"00:12:04.667 - 00:12:05.737", "00:12:04.667 - 00:12:05.737", 
"00:12:05.777 - 00:12:08.395", "00:12:05.777 - 00:12:08.395", 
"00:12:05.777 - 00:12:08.395", "00:12:05.777 - 00:12:08.395", 
"00:12:05.777 - 00:12:08.395", "00:12:05.777 - 00:12:08.395"), 
    Utterance = c("[what's] a !mountain! for you:", "[what's] a !mountain! for you:", 
    "[what's] a !mountain! for you:", "[what's] a !mountain! for you:", 
    "[what's] a !mountain! for you:", "[what's] a !mountain! for you:", 
    "[what's] a !mountain! for you:", "[what's] a !mountain! for you:", 
    "[what's] a !mountain! for you:", "[what's] a !mountain! for you:", 
    "(0.554)", "(0.554)", "(0.554)", "(0.554)", "((v: laughs))=", 
    "((v: laughs))=", "((v: laughs))=", "=I don't know the (Schauinsland) is a small mount[ain]", 
    "=I don't know the (Schauinsland) is a small mount[ain]", 
    "=I don't know the (Schauinsland) is a small mount[ain]", 
    "=I don't know the (Schauinsland) is a small mount[ain]", 
    "=I don't know the (Schauinsland) is a small mount[ain]", 
    "=I don't know the (Schauinsland) is a small mount[ain]"), 
    File = c("F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
    "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
    "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01"), Starttime_ms = c(722300L, 
    722300L, 722300L, 722300L, 722300L, 722300L, 722300L, 722300L, 
    722300L, 722300L, 724113L, 724113L, 724113L, 724113L, 724667L, 
    724667L, 724667L, 725777L, 725777L, 725777L, 725777L, 725777L, 
    725777L), Endtime_ms = c(724113, 724113, 724113, 724113, 
    724113, 724113, 724113, 724113, 724113, 724113, 724667, 724667, 
    724667, 724667, 725737, 725737, 725737, 728395, 728395, 728395, 
    728395, 728395, 728395), UttEnd = c(1813, 1813, 1813, 1813, 
    1813, 1813, 1813, 1813, 1813, 1813, 2367, 2367, 2367, 2367, 
    3437, 3437, 3437, 6055, 6055, 6055, 6055, 6055, 6055), UttStart = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1813, 1813, 1813, 1813, 2367, 
    2367, 2367, 3437, 3437, 3437, 3437, 3437, 3437), MM_by = c("A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", 
    "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), MM = c("aoi", 
    "aoi", "aoi", "aoi", "aoi", "aoi", "aoi", "aoi", "aoi", "aoi", 
    "aoi", "aoi", "aoi", "aoi", "aoi", "aoi", "aoi", "aoi", "aoi", 
    "aoi", "aoi", "aoi", "aoi"), MM_annotation = c("*", "B", 
    "*", "C", "A", "*", "C", "*", "A", "A", "C", "*", "A", "A", 
    "*", "A", "A", "*", "C", "A", "*", "A", "*"), dur = c(400L, 
    467L, 66L, 887L, 693L, 247L, 473L, 147L, 260L, 1820L, 353L, 
    207L, 567L, 567L, 1060L, 1060L, 1060L, 1000L, 1620L, 306L, 
    2314L, 2300L, 320L), end = c(400, 867, 933, 1820, 693, 940, 
    1413, 1560, 1820, 1820, 2166, 2373, 2380, 2380, 3427, 3427, 
    3427, 4437, 6057, 3743, 6057, 5737, 6057), start = c(0, 400, 
    867, 933, 0, 693, 940, 1413, 1560, 0, 1813, 2166, 1813, 1813, 
    2367, 2367, 2367, 3437, 4437, 3437, 3743, 3437, 5737)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -23L))
```

Comment: Instead of a segment, maybe you could use `geom_errorbar`.

Comment: Maybe not the aesthetic you want, but you could also consider using `geom_tile`, controlling the color and linewidth to get an outline that has the level of visibility you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot(data = df1) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = (start + end)/2, width = end - start,
                y = MM_by, height = 0.9,
                fill = MM_annotation), color = "black") +
  scale_y_discrete(name = NULL, limits = rev) +        
  facet_wrap(~ Utterance, scales = "free_x", ncol = 1) +
  
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("*" = "white",    
                                 "A" = "yellow",    
                                 "B" = "lawngreen",
                                 "C" = "cyan"),   
                      # rename legend key:
                      name = "Gaze to")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possible option using a second `geom_segment` coloured "black":

```r
ggplot(df1, aes(start, MM_by, xend = end, yend = MM_by, color = MM_annotation)) +
  geom_segment(aes(start, MM_by, xend = end, yend = MM_by), color = "black", size = 5, data = df1 |> filter(MM_annotation != "*")) +
  geom_segment(size = 4) +
  scale_y_discrete(name = NULL, limits = rev) +
  facet_wrap(~Utterance, scales = "free_x", ncol = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual(
    values = c(
      "*" = "white",
      "A" = "yellow",
      "B" = "lawngreen",
      "C" = "cyan"
    ),
    # rename legend key:
    name = "Gaze to"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-19 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>